# phpmyadmin search in enum type return nothing?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

[image]I got type ENUM in my DB, and want to do a simple search on that field.

I know there are values for that search, i select it on dropdowm list my value and ask for the result

Phpmyadmin said there is no result....

Why ?

version 3.5.3

Comment: Can you explain how you are selecting it?

Comment: i click on "search", then i click on the dropdown menu list on my value and then click on search...and no result...

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your search page?

Comment: Can you show the query it is executing?

Comment: i don't know how to do it, this is the problem, it seem that the query wasn't play, but it retunr an empty result

Comment: in fact, i can't do a search on this table for all kinds of fields...

Comment: i'll gona change all my enum type to something else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had change all enum type in my table, and search work again !
I didn't use Enum type anymore.